# Reset accelerometer in Android from ADB interface

Tags: android, command, accelerometer, adb

How can i reset the accelerometer sensisng device by an adb command? I want to achieve the reset action that tools like Advanced tools do with accelerometer, but i need it in adb command coz i want to make a init.d script for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the process I believe will allow you to do what you want but while I think the general instructions will work for all phones you will probably need to have a list of the different utilities each manufacturer uses and the config files they create ahead of time to make it work on all phones.  Also, for the following to work you will need a rooted phone.

1. Delete the config file in data/system/
2. Run the sensor calibration utility in /system/bin/.

For example, on the Samsung Galaxy you use the following:
/data/system/ms3c_yamaha.cfg
/system/bin/sensorcalibutil_yamaha